# MongoDB Get every Nth element of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been working on a small project that takes MQTT data from sensors and stores it in a MongoDB database. I'm working with nodeJS and mongoose. These are my schemas.

```js
export const SensorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    location: { type: String, required: true },
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    unit: { type: String, required: true },
    measurements: { type: [MeasurementSchema] }
},
{ 
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

export const MeasurementSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    value: {type: Number, required: true},
    time: {type: Date, required: true}
});
```

First I wrote a function that retrieves all measurements that were made in between two timestamps.

```js
const values = Sensor.aggregate([
                { $match: Sensor.getValuesFromPath(sensorPath) },
                { $unwind: "$measurements"},
                { $match: { "measurements.time": { $gte: startTime,  $lte: endTime} }},
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$measurements" } },
                { $project: { _id: 0}},
                { $sort: {time: 1}}
            ]).exec();
```

In order to draw a graph in the UI, I need to somehow sort and then limit the data that gets sent to the client. I want to send every Nth Value in a certain interval to ensure that the data somewhat resembles the course of the data.
I would prefer a solution that doesn't fetch all the data from the database.

How would I go about doing this on the db? Can I somehow access the positional index of an element after sorting it? Is `$arrayElemAt` or `$elemMatch` the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Befure you run `$unwind` you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to apply start/end Date filtering. This will allow you to process `measurements` as an array. In the next step you can get every `N-th` element by using [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) to define a list of indexes and [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to retrieve elements from these indexes:

```
const values = Sensor.aggregate([
                { $match: Sensor.getValuesFromPath(sensorPath) },                
                { $addFields: { 
                    measurements: { 
                        $filter: { 
                            input: "$measurements", 
                            cond: { $and: [ 
                                    { $gte: [ "$$this.time", startTime ] }, 
                                    { $lte: [ "$$this.time", endTime ] } 
                                ] 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } },
                { $addFields: { 
                    measurements: { 
                        $map: { 
                            input: input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$measurements" }, N ] }, 
                            as: "index",
                            in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$measurements", "$$index" ] }
                        } 
                    } 
                } },
                { $unwind: "$measurements" },
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$measurements" } },
                { $project: { _id: 0}},
                { $sort: {time: 1}}
            ]).exec();
```

Comment: Is `$unwind` a very expensive operation or why do you prefer it to do all the filtering before `$unwind`? Or would it otherwise not work?

Comment: @LucasEngleder no, `$unwind` is fine and you can return array elements as separate documents but to get `n-th` elements you need to know the context of entire data set so it has to be an array at that point

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation (i) retrieves all measurements that were made in between two timestamps, (ii) sorts by timestamp for each sensor, and (iii) gets every Nth value (specified by the variable EVERY_N).

***Sample documents*** (with some arbitrary data for testing):

```
{
  name: "s-1",
  location: "123",
  type: "456",
  measurements: [ { time: 2, value: 12 }, { time: 3, value: 13 }, 
                  { time: 4, value: 15 }, { time: 5, value: 22 }, 
                  { time: 6, value: 34 }, { time: 7, value: 9 }, 
                  { time: 8, value: 5 }, { time: 9, value: 1 }, 
  ]
},
{
  name: "s-2",
  location: "789",
  type: "900",
  measurements: [ { time: 1, value: 31 }, { time: 3, value: 32 }, 
                  { time: 4, value: 35 }, { time: 6, value: 39 },
                  { time: 7, value: 6}, { time: 8, value: 70 }, 
                  { time: 9, value: 74 }, { time: 10, value: 82 }
  ]
}
```

The ***aggregation***:

```
var startTime = 3, endTime = 10
var EVERY_N = 2   // value can be 3, etc.

db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $unwind: "$measurements" 
  },
  { 
      $match: { 
          "measurements.time": { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $sort: { name: 1, "measurements.time": 1 } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "$name", 
          measurements: { $push: "$measurements" }, 
          doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          "doc.measurements": "$measurements" 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
           measurements: { 
               $reduce: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$measurements" } ] }, 
                    initialValue: [ ],
                    in: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ { $mod: [ "$$this", EVERY_N ] }, 0 ] }, 
                                   { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$measurements", "$$this" ] } ] ] }, 
                                   "$$value" 
                             ]
                    }
               }
           }
      } 
  }
] )
```